# How to easily duplicate helm charts

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

10 microservices on kubernetes with helm3 charts, and saw that all of them have similar structure standard, deployment, service, hpa, network policies etc. and basically the `<helm_chart_name>/templates` directory is 99% same on all with some `if` statements on top of file whether we want to deploy that resource,

```sh
{{ if .Values.hpa.create }}
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.deployment.name }}
...
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
...
{{ end }}
```

and in values passing  yes/no whether we want it - Is there some tool to easily create template for the helm charts ? To create Helm chart with this 5 manifests pre-populated with the reference to values as above ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is the [Library Charts](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/library_charts/):

> A library chart is a type of Helm chart that defines chart primitives
> or definitions which can be shared by Helm templates in other charts.
> This allows users to share snippets of code that can be re-used across
> charts, avoiding repetition and keeping charts DRY.

You can find more details and examples in the linked documentation.

Answer (score 4):

I think closest thing to the thing I want is https://helm.sh/docs/topics/library_charts/

Comment: It looks like you have posted this while I was still writing my own answer which points to exactly the same solution :) Anyway, I believe this is the best thing you can get for your use case.